# ssh-key public regex validation

Tags: javascript, php, regex, ssh-keys

I have the following problem I am trying to make a validation for ssh-keys (public) so that the customer has to give me a real ssh-key. Can someone tell me how to make the 'regex' so that this is correct? I have something like this: `ssh-rsa AAAA[0-9A-Za-z+/]+[=]{0,3} ([^@]+@[^@]+)#` but this does not work. Error: `preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex might be fine. You should use a **delimiter** in your regex

```php
$regex = '/ssh-rsa AAAA[0-9A-Za-z+\/]+[=]{0,3} ([^@]+@[^@]+)#/'
```

Comment: The `/` is the delimiter

Comment: Then comes the problem `preg_match(): Unknown modifier ']' `

Comment: Escape the `/` that is in your regex
`
$regex = '/ssh-rsa AAAA[0-9A-Za-z+\/]+[=]{0,3} ([^@]+@[^@]+)#/'
`
Or use a delimiter that is not alphanumeric or backslash and not in your regex

Comment: I have it so now `/ssh-rsa AAAA[0-9A-Za-z+\/]+[=]{0,3} ([^@]+@[^@]+)#/` but it say `The key format is invalid.` i used this `ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIJhe,06LaPXiCTQLVf2Dq5RPnz2Gzx0rDybRKQPUhzByhm test@local.host`

Comment: If you want to know what happened: After a delimiter you can add modifiers (like case insensitive search `i`, because the string started with / your delimiter is /. Because there is a / in your regex, it stops there and tries to read the modifiers, of which the first is ], which is not a modifier.

Comment: ssh-ed25519 not matches ssh-rsa :wink:

Comment: i am a hosting entrepreneur. Should I only allow rsa or everything else? if so what would the regex look like?

Comment: This matches your example:
```/ssh-[^\s]* AAAA[0-9A-Za-z+\/,]+ ([^@]+@[^@]+)/```

Comment: ok thanks to you

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/qPqzqN/1

Comment: If you want to disallow anything but rsa you should get a message "The key format is invalid", right

Comment: yes it comes then

Comment: now i have one question i dont know if you know but i have this in laravel. now i will get the https://i.imgur.com/YX70v1n.png from this picture the `algo` from `hash` but how? $key['hash'] dont work

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that

Comment: no problem but thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that rsa is no longer the recommended algorithm. As such, one should support multiple algorithms.

Running

```
ssh -Q key
```

Shows the available algorithms. Right now, used algorithms are:

- rsa
- ed25519
- dss
- ecdsa

Also, the comment after the key is optional.

```
ssh-(ed25519|rsa|dss|ecdsa) AAAA(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})( [^@]+@[^@]+)?
```

The first couple of characters of the base64 encoded string are actually the algorithm in base64:

```
echo "AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAA" | base64 --decode
> ssh-ed25519
```

So if you want to be even more paranoid, you can match these first couple characters.